# Authorization of List/Search endpoints in REST API

Tags: api, rest, permissions, authorization, abac

I want to understand how to deal with authorization in REST API with endpoints like below

- `GET /resource/:id`
- `DELETE /resource/:id`
- `GET /resource`

**Assumptions**

- User Bob is authenticated.
- Bob only owns resources with id `1,2,4,5,6` but `3`
- System has an Access Control and Busines Logic Layers
- The business layer doesn't have any awareness of data ownership
- Access Control Layer has `policies` for `resources` and `users` and it can check if users have the right to access resources and
  reject the request with `HTTP403` or pass it to the Business Logic
  layer to be processed

**Scenario**

- Bob sends a request to `GET /resource/2`, the application returns resource details with `HTTP 200`
- Bob sends a request to `DELETE /resource/3`, and the application returns `HTTP 403`.
- Bob sends a request to list resources `GET /resources?page=1&pageSize=10`, the application returns resource summaries of `1,2,4,5,6` but `3`

**Problem**

The Access control layer can prevent(403) access to a specific resource by checking the claims of the user for a given resource with defined policies.
But It should not be PREVENTED(403) when accessing search endpoints. It should be FILTERED.

**Approach 1**

- It may assumed that search would include summaries of resources that is not owned by the authenticated user.

**Approach 2**

- Search endpoints may be entirely separated and have the awareness of resource ownership and have the responsibility of resolving ownership and filtering.
- Other endpoints stay clean by having only business logic.

**Questions**

- Which alternative approach is better?
- Is there any alternative?
- Am I mixing concepts of data ownership, access control, and business logic?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing these concepts. Let's start from the very beginning:

If a particular user, in this case Bob, is authenticated and his authentication records have policy which defines access to a particular set of resources ( or defines prevention of access to particular set of resources ) then that status should be PREVENTED. Why?

Bob is PREVENTED from accessing particular resources. FILTERED means filtering data and that's something that you can do even when Bob has access to the data. When Bob receives 200 OK status with records that he wanted, internal functionalities of the API can still filter the data that will be adapted to the policy Bobs authentication records hold.

If in our database we have set of records like this: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
And we want to create policies that will prevent some users from access a particular record then we can have policies set up in the way where we describe records that define access a particular user has. On example policy can define a record that holds number 3 in a array ( `[3]` ) and based on this we can create a logic that would obviously filter out the data that's in the array and return `[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`.

However, this model heavily depends on how your data is structured. Questions you might want to ask yourself before designing your policy records:

- How are my records structured? Do they have records/tables that I can split my data into? If they do, I can define something like `<COLLECTION/TABLE_NAME>:<ACCESS_LEVEL>` which would in this case yield `numbers:*` or `numbers:[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`.
- Can I save access needed into my records? Common practice is to have needed access definitions saved in the records or related records of the data you save. Something like: `access_needed: [ "read", "write" ]`

Again, it all comes down to your records and based on that you can structure how to define your policy format.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My confusion starts when `internal logic adapted to the policy`
Here I feel like authorization logic leaks into the business layer.
That's obvious I should hold a resource-user mapping somewhere. If a policy is a place then is it the responsibility of the access layer to filter ? 
Should I do the query to the database without the 'resource' filter and then filter it after in the access control layer? 
---

Comment: Once I add logic into the database query of checking data ownership, something like `where r.owner = ownerId` It means, the record itself has awareness of data ownership + I am doing an authorization logic here even though I only filter the results. Maybe this way of thinking causes the problem.

Comment: It heavily depends on how you structured your application. You shouldn't mix authorization logic with function logic, they should stay separated. Your best course here would be to, instead of actual data records, you make user records aware of permissions and ownership they have. That way you can have a query during authorization that would fetch ownership data also and based on that you can validate whether or not you should return prevented status on access layer.

Comment: That means, having one query during authorization, then validating whether parameters from the request for the particular record are valid by filtering trough ownership data fetched from the user records, then if they are proceed to the function, if not return an prevented status.

Comment: You definitely should not do a query and then filter. Everything that you can filter out do it via query because sometimes database calls can be costly.